# how to use existing conda environment as a AzureML environment

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I have created a Azure Compute target and using the notebooks from it. I want to create a conda environment using Notebook Terminal and install my own packages and use it in AzureML experiment environment.

Comment: I don't get why someone downvote this question. I would request, please mention the reason to downvote question

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and the answer can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-access-terminal#add-new-kernels

The basic steps are:

- Create your conda environment with the terminal
- Activate the environment
- `conda install pip`
- `conda install ipykernel`
- `python -m ipykernel install --user --name newenv --display-name "Python (newenv)"`

After reloading the portal you can select the kernel in the list.

Answer (score -2):

Fist make sure we install `conda` using Notebook Terminal.

We can create an environment from existing conda environment. This make it easy to reuse your local interactive environment in Azure ML remote runs. For example, if we've created conda environment using

```
conda create -n mycondaenv
```

We can create Azure ML environment out of that conda environment using

```
myenv = Environment.from_existing_conda_environment(name="myenv", conda_environment_name="mycondaenv")
```